# I share desktop, but others cannot control it

Tags: live-meeting

I am using LiveMeeting.

I schedule a meeting and invite attendees.  I am able to share my desktop, but I do not see any option to allow my attendees to control the desktop.

They do not see anything on their screens that helps them ask for Control of my desktop either.

How do I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before participants can control your shared desktop, they must be LiveMeeting Presenters. There are 2 ways to do that.

1. BEFORE MEETING: Send them the "Join as Presenter" link (instead of "Join as Attendee") OR
2. IN MEETING: From the "Attendees" menu, right-click on the Attendee name and choose "Promote to Presenter." (They'll get confirmation and their LiveMeeting icon changes.)

Once the user's a Presenter, there are 2 ways to give them control.

1. AS HOST: The LiveMeeting menu bar has 4 icons, including "Give Control." Choose "Give Control" and a list of Presenters appears. Pick the user who needs control.
2. AS VIEWER: Open the "Content" menu, which shows everything shared by the host. They can right-click on your "Desktop" and pick "Request Control" from the pop-up menu. A request appears on the host screen, which you accept.

Either of these should give desktop control to LiveMeeting attendees, once they're promoted to a Presenter.